# Linuxカーネルをアップデートすると動かない、あるいは挙動がおかしくなるアプリを教えてください。

Tags: linux, docker

『アプリがLinuxのカーネルバージョンに依存するのでカーネルをアップデートできない』と聞きますが、具体的に何のアプリがどのようになるのか知りたいです。
例えば、下記URLに書かれているようにremovedされたABIを使っていたために動かなくなってしまったアプリはあるのでしょうか。
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/Documentation/ABI

あるいはカーネル内のコードが変わったことで処理速度が変わり、マルチスレッド/マルチプロセスで影響を与える例などはあるのでしょうか。

特定のハードウェアを制御する目的で、専用のモジュールを前提としているプログラムは含みません。glibcに依存するなどユーザ空間の問題ではなく、アプリがLinuxのカーネルに依存し、カーネルバージョンを上げると動かなくなる or 挙動がおかしくなる例を知りたいのです。たぶんこのような問題はLinuxカーネルバージョンを変えられないDockerで起こると考えています。

Comment: 質問タイトルからすると世に出ているアプリの例を知りたいのだと思いますが、Linux用のアプリだとしても数多くありコレといった明確な回答がありません。
例えば質問を「カーネルをアップデートすることでアプリに及ぶ影響は？」などにすれば多少は範囲が狭まるのではないでしょうか？(これでもまだ広いと感じますが)
カーネルをアプデできない(というよりするとアプリが動かなくなる)ような内容自体に関してはアプリが使用しているモジュールなどがカーネルに依存している場合、アプデするとモジュールが使えなくなるのでアプリが動作しないなどが考えられます。(モジュールがつられてアプデされると挙動が変わる可能性もありますね)

Comment: 質問者さんは色々なところで聞くと書かれていますし、Myaku さんも数多くあるとコメントされていますが、そんなにある物なのでしょうか。私は一つも思い付きません。この質問は現時点で「質問の範囲が広すぎる」に3票入っておりクローズされそうな気配があります。しかし、該当するプログラムが多くあるのだとしても、私にはそれが常識的に知られている事とは思えないです。「沢山ある。例えばこれ。他はこういった探し方で見付かる」といった形の回答でもあれば有意義な Q&A になると思います。ご存知の方にはぜひ回答を書いて欲しいです。クローズには反対です。

Comment: 改善待ちになりましたので、以下2点を提案します。 1) 特定のハードウェアを制御する目的で、専用のモジュールを前提としているプログラムがありますが、そういった物を含むか否かの明記。 2) ここ（Stack Overflow）でリストを完成させたいのではなく、あくまでも質問者さんが作成するにあたって必要な情報を質問しているのだ、という形、それが明らかな表現への変更。

Comment: 「質問の範囲が広すぎる」については、オフトピックのテンプレが貧弱なので仕方ないかなというところでしょう。この質問の問題点は「（なんでも可）」とタイトルに明記されているように、広くアンケート的に情報収集するものであること、質問(「質問」と呼んでいいのかどうかも怪しいですが)の目的が「リストを作りたい」であることでしょう。(サーバ構築に関するQ&Aは日本語版スタックオーバーフローではオントピックだと言う前提で)例えば、メールサーバを構築する際、SPAMの発信元のブラックリストの存在は極めて有用なものですが、果たして、そのようなブラックリストを自分で作りたいからSPAMサイトの情報を何でもいいから教えてくれ、という質問が書かれたらそれはこのサイトの趣旨に沿うものだと思われるでしょうか。(＞ @mjy さん)と、ここまで書いたところでコメントが追記されましたが、元質問者さんが趣旨を汲み取って自ら質問を改善するか、それがなされないのであれば、こちらは一旦クローズして mjy さん自らが「有意義なQ&A」となる質問を再投稿されるのが筋であろうと思います。

Comment: @OOPer Stack Overflow で許容される程度の意義があると思い「有意義」と書きました。私自身にとって、質問の作成というコストに見あうほど有意義かは別の問題ですので、「筋」とは思いません。これ以上は Meta 的な内容かと思いますので、議論が必要なら Meta サイトでお願いします。

Comment: 興味本位でなんでもいいから事例が知りたいと読めてしまうとクローズ投票されがちです。「カーネルのセキュリティホールを攻撃するプログラムがカーネルを対策済みのバージョンに更新したら動かなくなった」のような自明な事例が知りたいわけではないでしょう。背景を説明し求める回答の方向性を明確にした方が良いように思います

Answer (score 2):

この事例をアプリの問題と考えるかは微妙ですが、VMware Server 2を利用していた頃、ドライバのコンパイルが通らなくなるから、という理由でkernelのバージョンを上げられなかった事があります。

また、やはりアプリではないですが、xfsにバグがあった時期があり、運悪くその頃のカーネルを使って出荷されていたNASがそこそこありました。この手のNASのカーネルを上げると、バグが修正されたファイルシステムが適用され、ファイルシステムが一切読めなくなるため、カーネルを上げることができませんでした。ARM OABI依存の問題だったと記憶しています。

どちらも記憶で書いているため詳細が曖昧ですが、質問者の意図する回答かわからないため、覚えている範囲で通りすがりのコメントとして残していきます。興味があれば検索等で詳細が見つかると思います。